# XChat - Negotiations tooke too many packets

Tags: irc, xchat

I am trying to connect to an IRC server. I am receiving the following error:

```
Sending 95 bytes of handshake data
State is I_CONTINUE_NEEDED (size=0, extra=0)
Received 975 bytes
State is $80090331 (size=975, extra=0)
... (repeats a few times)
Negotiations took too many packets

Connection failed. Error: SSL failure
```

Does anyone know what is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, XChat uses the Windows SSL library if OpenSSL is not installed. So, just installing the open SSL library fixed the problem http://www.mirc.com/ssl.html